# User cannot login with blank password on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, passwords, login, login-screen

I created a user account that has no password.

When trying to login as that user from the Welcome Screen, Windows says:

> Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in. For example: blank passwords aren't allowed, sign-in times are limited, or a policy restriction has been enforced.

[image]

So, the question is:

- How do I disable account restrictions preventing this user from signing in?
- How do I allow blank passwords

### System

- Windows 10 Pro
- Not domain joined

Local Computer Policy/Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Credentials Delegation:

| Setting | State | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Allow delegating default credentials with NTML-only server authentication | Not configured | No |
| Allow delegating default credentials | Not configured | No |
| Encryption Oracle Remediation | Not configured | No |
| Allow delegating fresh credentials | Not configured | No |
| Allow delegating fresh credentials with NTLM-only server authentication | Not configured | No |
| Remote host allows delegation of non-exportable credentials | Not configured | No |
| Allow delegating saved credentials | Not configured | No |
| Allow delegating saved credentials with NTLM-only server | Not configured | No |
| Deny delegating default credentials | Not configured | No |
| Deny delegating fresh credentials | Not configured | No |
| Deny delegating saved credentials | Not configured | No |
| Restrict delegation of credentials to remote servers | Not configured | No |

### Minimum password length of zero

In order to allow a user password to be blank, you need to make sure that the Password Policy **Minimum password length** is set to 0 (the default):

Local Computer Policy/Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Account Policies/Password Policy:

| Policy | Security Setting |
| --- | --- |
| Minimum password length | 0 characters |

That lets you **set** a password that is blank. But that doesn't help you actually login, which gives the initial error that we're trying to solve.

### Bonus Reading

- [Guide to Fix Account Restrictions are Preventing this User from Signing In Error](https://www.techinpost.com/account-restrictions-are-preventing-this-user-from-signing-in/) *(which suggests turning on the ability for people with blank passwords to login remotely - which of course we do not want. We want them to only be able to login locally at the console.)*

Comment: https://www.techinpost.com/account-restrictions-are-preventing-this-user-from-signing-in/

Comment: "even more strongly enforced in Windows 11." - This is simply not true.  I have a WIndows 11 21H2 VM with several users without a password.

Comment: If this machine is connected to an AD domain, the simple answer to your question is what you want is not possible due to the current password policies configured by your AD Administration.  If this is a local machine, you modify the relevant group policies to allow a blank password.   Post a screenshot of [these](https://i1.wp.com/www.techinpost.com/wp-content/uploads/step1.png?w=799&ssl=1) that provides the configuration of these group policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you have changed the Minimum Password Length setting, but there are other settings that could do this that you should verify.

1. Open gpedit.msc
2. Go to: Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Password Policy
3. Make sure all of the settings look like this:

`Enforce password history: 0 passwords remembered`

`Maximum password age: 0`

`Minimum password age: 0 days`

`Minimum password length: 0 characters`

`Password must meet complexity requirements: Disabled`

This should allow no password logins.

Alternatively, the way I know that works 100% of the time is to simply use a blank password when installing Windows. That will always work.

Answer (score 2):

Using RegEdit, you can go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa` and set the value of `LimitBlankPasswordUse` to `0`